# My script's if statement isn't working on my wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to write a script that runs on all of my WordPress pages except the home page. Here's what I'm using (I added it to the  tag) but it's not working. It works without the if statement, which I added myself. So what am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var totalheight = 0;
  if (jQuery("body:not(.home)")) {
    jQuery(".et-l--header .et_builder_inner_content .et_pb_section").each(function(){
      totalheight = totalheight + jQuery(this).outerHeight();
    });
    totalheight = totalheight + "px";
    jQuery("#et-main-area").css("padding-top",totalheight);
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: What's "not working" about it?  At a glance, that `if` condition makes no sense to me.  The `jQuery` function will always return a valid object.  Did you intend to test that object for something?

Comment: The if statement should be checking to make sure the the <body> class is not "home". Should I remove the jQuery in front of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a comment on the question:

> The if statement should be checking to make sure the the  class is not "home".

Currently it's only checking if jQuery successfully *queried* the DOM.  The jQuery function will always (unless something goes horribly wrong) return a jQuery object.  So this `if` condition will always be `true`:

```
if (jQuery("body:not(.home)")) {
```

That object could contain references to *zero or more* DOM elements, but it's still a valid object.  To test if it found at least one matching element, check its length:

```
if (jQuery("body:not(.home)").length > 0) {
```